# C# - Declaring and initializing a nested array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dictionary, initialization

Problem: I need to create a collection with string keys, that have two fields, which contain an array of string keys. This will be referenced in multiple functions inside the .cs file's `namespace` section, not just in a single function or class. The data inside it will not change, outside of its initialization.

In Lua, this is extremely trivial and easy to do. Like so:

```
local tableCulturesToRaceGender = {};

tableCulturesToRaceGender["Northern Empire"] = { 
    male={
        "EmpireMale",
        "BattaniaMale",
        "KhuzaitMale"},
    female = {
        "EmpireFemale"
        }
    }

--[[
--Visual layout of the nested array
tableCulturesToRaceGender["Northern Empire"]
    male
        [1] = "EmpireMale"
        [2] = "BattaniaMale"
        [3] = "KhuzaitMale"
    female
        [1] = "EmpireFemale"
--]]

local function UseTheTable()

    local strEntry = tableCulturesToRaceGender["Northern Empire"].male[2]
    --StrEntry is now filled with: BattaniaMale

end
```

I'm having a hell of a time figuring this out. All sort of caveats, boilerplate, `{get; set;}` drudgery, getter and setter functions, stuff about mutability, how you can't `readonly list<>`, etc. And then there's the scope; putting a list in a namespace cannot be done, putting it in a class doesn't work due to mutability, etc.

It's an overcomplicated mess, with lots of jargon intended for people who already know what everything means. I've been at this for a couple hours, and I'm more confused than when I started.

So, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use classes and generic containers for your data. You can initialize a class so that clients cannot change the data using `private fields` that can only be `get`ed and not `set`ed by a `public property` (that is C# jargon and if you want to use C#, you must learn it---sorry). You can use an interface so that the different 'empires' have the same kind of data but different values (and more optional stuff if needed). This is one approach that is very idiomatic in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Culture
{
    public interface IRaces
    {
        public string Empire { get; }
        public List<string> Male { get; }
        public List<string> Female { get; }
    }
    public class NorthernEmpire : IRaces
    {
        private readonly string _empire = "Northern";
        public string Empire => _empire;
        private readonly List<string> _male = new() { "Empire", "Battania", "Khuzait" };
        public List<string> Male => _male;
        private readonly List<string> _female = new() { "Empire" };
        public List<string> Female => _female;
        private readonly string _fightingStyle = "whatever";
        public string FightingStyle => _fightingStyle;

    }
    public class SouthernEmpire : IRaces
    {
        private readonly string _empire = "Southern";
        public string Empire => _empire;
        private readonly List<string> _male = new() { "Empire" };
        public List<string> Male => _male;
        private readonly List<string> _female = new() { "Empire", "Battania", "Khuzait" };
        public List<string> Female => _female;

    }
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<IRaces> raceList = new();
            raceList.Add(new NorthernEmpire());
            raceList.Add(new SouthernEmpire());
            foreach (IRaces races in raceList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Empire: {races.Empire}:");
                foreach (string maleRace in races.Male)
                    Console.WriteLine($"\tMale race: {maleRace}");
                foreach (string femaleRace in races.Female)
                    Console.WriteLine($"\tFemale race: {femaleRace}");
                if (races is NorthernEmpire)
                    Console.WriteLine($"\tFighting Style: {((NorthernEmpire)races).FightingStyle}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Empire: Northern:
        Male race: Empire
        Male race: Battania
        Male race: Khuzait
        Female race: Empire
        Fighting Style: whatever
Empire: Southern:
        Male race: Empire
        Female race: Empire
        Female race: Battania
        Female race: Khuzait
```

Comment: You may want to nest them like they requested.

Comment: Well, they are nested in the sense that my solution uses a class to contain the arrays. The OP appears to want to have static data using C# patterns. I would not structure this data representation in C# using a nested array or a dictionary. FWIW...

Comment: All good, just putting it out there. They're using what looks like an object so it's probably good enough.

Comment: Good in the hood. You are right that the OP also asked to see nested arrays at work. Maybe next time ;-).

Comment: This looks really good. So it's a separate class, which is referenced from other classes. Right, that makes more sense. Make the actual data private, and the public properties are just pointers. That makes more sense, versus the boilerplate that I was seeing elsewhere. I'd have to make multiple classes for the multiple arrays, which is fine for this small set of data. Knowing how to do it in one class would be appreciated tho.

Comment: I updated my answer showing how to do this with `interfaces`. In C# an `interface` provides a contract so that a client can be sure it can find certain methods, properties etc. in an object. The object implementing the interface may have more stuff in it as well, but not less. This is shown with the addition of `FightingStyle` as a property of the (I guess) more warlike northerners.

Comment: By the way, just to be clear a `property` is not at all the same thing as a pointer. The `=>` notation is just short hand for `get` (and sometimes other things in C#) and has nothing to do with the `->` operator for pointers in C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty much word for word translation of your Lua code would be like:

```
var tableCulturesToRaceGender = new
{
    northernEmpire = new
    { 
        male = new[]
        {
            "EmpireMale",
            "BattaniaMale",
            "KhuzaitMale"
        },
        female = new[]
        {
            "EmpireFemale"
        }
    }
};

var result = tableCulturesToRaceGender.northernEmpire.male[0];
```

> I'm having a hell of a time figuring this out. All sort of caveats, boilerplate, {get; set;} drudgery, getter and setter functions, stuff about mutability, how you can't readonly list<>, etc. And then there's the scope; putting a list in a namespace cannot be done, putting it in a class doesn't work due to mutability, etc.

Careful with that rant, it only shows you didn't bother to read any documentation. You haven't said a single true word in that entire paragraph, not to mention the next one.

Comment: The nested array example I didn't bother to give. Also, my example doesn't show how to make an array of 'Cultures' that are represented by classes. This would require an `interface`. +1 for calling the OP out on the rant. Not understanding something doesn't make it bad---a lesson for us all these days...

Comment: Updated my answer showing the use of interfaces. May be overkill for the OP. Mine is the 'right way' (scalable, etc.) way to do this as C# intended. This answer is the direct translation of the lua.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using **Enumerations** in C# ?
In your collection, add a get-only property with the enum below as output type.
Enumerations are not mutable as they're constants in reality.
And you can decorate each entry with custom attribute if you want too.

```
enum MaleEntries
{
    EmpireMale = 1,
    BattaniaMale = 2,
    KhuzaitMale = 3
}
```

and

```
enum FemaleEntries
{
    EmpireFemale = 1
}
```

Comment: `enum`s is another good way to approach to this problem. However, this answer doesn't explain how use them in a collection.

Comment: Hmm, enums do look good here. The trouble here, is that I need the strings (e.g `EmpireMale`) rather than the integers, which are then passed as an argument to another function. And yeah, I would like to use them in a collection so I know exactly how to do that. There are few enough that I could use a bunch of `elseif` checks, but bleh.